# JavaScript OOP: Did I miss something on variable scopes and anonymous functions?

Tags: javascript, oop, events, event-handling, observer-pattern

I'm getting some weird behavior as I'm trying to implement a little bit of event handling to my JavaScript-game. I'm not a JavaScript expert and I kind of feel like I've missed something essential but I can't figure out what's going wrong.

I made this **EventManager** "class":

```
function EventManager(events) {

    var _events;

    this.addEventCallback = function(eventName, callback) {
        _events[eventName].push(callback);
    }

    this.fireEvent = function(eventName) {
        for (var i = 0; i < _events[eventName].length; i++) {
            _events[eventName][i]();
        }
    }

    // constructor

    __construct = function(that) {
        _events = [];
        for (key in events) {
            _events[events[key]] = new Array();
        }
    }(this)

}
```

In my **GameObject** class, I use my EventManager like this:

```
function GameObject() {

    // define event ids
    var _events = {
        MOVE_START: 0,
        MOVE_STOP: 1
    }

    var _eventManager;

    // how i fire the event:

    this.moveLeft = function() {
        if (!_isMoving()) {
                _eventManager.fireEvent(_events.MOVE_START);
                _velocity = new Vector(-1, 0);
        }
    }

    // event registration "interface"

    this.onMoveStart = function(fn) {
        _eventManager.addEventCallback(_events.MOVE_START, fn);
    }

    this.onMoveStop = function(fn) {
        _eventManager.addEventCallback(_events.MOVE_STOP, fn);
    }

    // constructor

    __construct = function(that) {
        _eventManager = new EventManager(_events);
    }(this);

}
```

So then I test things out:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < _gameObjects.length; i++) {
        console.log("event handler to object number " + i);
        _gameObjects[i].onMoveStart(function() {
            console.log("object number " + i + " started moving");
        });
    }
```

I expect the output to be "object number 0 started moving" when I move the first object and "object number 1 started moving" when I move the second one and so on.

The output is always: **"object number 3 started moving"**. It always says object number 3, no matter which object I move. The weirdest part to me is, that I only have 3 objects in my `_gameObjects`-Array so I would at least expect it to say "object numer 2 started moving".

I tried doing this:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < _gameObjects.length; i++) {
        var num = i;
        console.log("event handler to object number " + num);
        _gameObjects[i].onMoveStart(function() {
            console.log("object number " + num + " started moving");
        });
    }
```

Then, she output is always: **"object number 2 started moving"**.

I'm sure that the objects are not all the same, as I can move the ones I want to.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Your `__construct` is a global variable which you overwrite from each constructor! And you really don't need that IEFE, your `EventManager`/`GameObject` constructor functions are closures enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is "Yes", i.e. you did miss something about variable scope in JS anonymous functions.  I recommend reading Javascript Closures for Dummies, an article which is quoted in its entirety here: [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

To get your test code working, you could do this:

```
function notifyStart(i) {
    return function() {
        console.log("object number " + i + " started moving");
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < _gameObjects.length; i++) {
    _gameObjects[i].onMoveStart( notifyStart(i) );
}
```

Comment: No problem :)  Do have a look at the article, and others about closures in JavaScript until you've got your head around them. It might take a while, but it's worth it to understand what is IMO a very important feature of the language!